# Unable to ADD Indian Payment Method in Whatsapp Business API using Payment Methods (https://developers.facebook.com/)

Tags: whatsapp

I have read the [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/pricing/) regarding [payments](https://scontent.fhyd1-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.8562-6/271752492_358364582289212_6498511227670509489_n.pdf?_nc_cat=110&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=ae5e01&_nc_ohc=oSQxkPGh1oMAX_dJvTF&_nc_ht=scontent.fhyd1-4.fna&oh=00_AT_qbFFcaqTWw-DPvuWGIFx9LrHv_gtRkuR3musrg5-kGg&oe=6301607E) and also raised the customer support [ticket](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/339201598293146/) in Meta for Developers(Developer Support) and find the relevant [question](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/436240628328875/) but I didn't get the proper solution on how to add Indian Payment Method.

Does anyone know anything about adding payment method in India? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Latest Update:**

WhatsApp Business API has launched payment support in **India** country from 20 Oct 2022,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-platform/changelog#october-20--2022

> Note: Your location and currency cannot be changed once set, refer to [the documentation](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/488291839463771)

---

<strike>*There is no India country on the Payment settings page, see [the available countries](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/419761233006366),*</strike>

[First Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcNNr.png)

But you can try selecting a random country and you will see the INR currency,

[Second Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSy3R.png)

Comment: thxs for your comment and I have a query that is if I do payment like above answer (changing the country and selecting the INR) it will create any payment issues (any legal issue) or not.

Comment: currently, I don't know, but we have set up payment method this way, I will update my answer when I get information from my organization.

Comment: Hi @turivishal , can I get any update from  your commented answer because my payment method is not working fine now. Please help me

Comment: Yeah, even my is not working now, it shows payment failed, I asked the support team, and they said the payment method is not available in India, you can't use it after 1000 free messages over in a month, and they will provide support in India and other counties soon. but I wonder, we have sent 25k messages in 2 months, and still, we can able to send the messages even though it shows payment failed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and I have read the same [payment method is not available in india](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/488291839463771?helpref=search&sr=1&query=Add%20a%20Credit%20Card%20to%20Your%20WhatsApp%20Business%20Platform%20Account) using this document but initially I able to send the message using your answer(changing country) but now  it shows payment failed, so can your tell me how you sending the messages ? (we have sent 25k messages in 2 months, and still, we can able to send the messages even though it shows payment failed.) I'm also wonder on this. It help me a lot.

Comment: It is working by itself, we have not done anything, for a hint we have unique customers so almost 25k are unique phone numbers, and we got an increased 1lakh message limit because of that, so I am not sure how it allows us to send messages.

Comment: @ashok WhatsApp Business API has launched payment support in India country from [20 Oct 2022](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-platform/changelog#october-20--2022).